Regarding investemnt scams on instagram
I want to ask you about the Instagram situation i am facing as I got an Instagram user page called jaydalee.martin which guarantees that we can get 11,500$ by transferring 200$ etransfer and when I paid it they asked me and sent me the email of approved my request and told me to pay an Activation fee of 699$to get the amount and additional after paying that this message was sended:                                    We sent off the money to you but it went on pending…because it’s the first time you’re investing with us plus it seems like it’s the first time you’re receiving such an amount at once to your interac e-transfer so it’s on hold. Please don’t be discouraged because your $12,400 is ready there’s only one small obstacle in the way it’s a $1,559.99 fee this is a processing fee. The reason for this fee is because the money has way surpassed your transfer limit so you’ll have to pay the $1,559.99 in order for them to release your funds okay. Once this fee is paid your $12,500 + $700 + $650 will go straight in your account and it won’t takes 2 minutes… at the moment it’s at 99% in our pending transit so you’re going to do this (FINAL) transaction this is also apart of your(FDIC)/(CRA) insurance fee so that the process can be completed we enforce costumer protection and legislation, regulations and industry commitments by federal regulated financial entities….also the FDIC Federal Deposit Insurance covers all deposits to your accounts so that you can get your $13,850.00 now so please told me this is legitimate. So tell is this is a scam or real?

If you have to ask if it's a scam., it's a scam. Period.

And to be absolutely clear, despite "because your $12,400 is ready", there is no "your money" waiting to be collected. It doesn't exist. It's just numbers in emails to make you pay more.

Aside from all the other red flags here, one good rule to follow is that any time you have to pay money to receive money, it's a scam. A legitimate service would just take any fees out of the total instead of making you pay in advance.


we can get 11,500$ by transferring 200$ etransfer

Nobody gives money away like this. If they really had an investment like this they'd keep it quiet to benefit themselves and their friends. It's a well know scam called the "Advance Fee Scam". If you search for "Advance Fee Scam" on this site you'll find dozens of examples. Any legitimate business would simply deduct your fees from the money they already hold from you.

Once this fee is paid your $12,500 + $700 + $650 will go straight in
your account

No, once this fee is paid, they'll discover you need to pay taxes first, and when you pay the taxes, they'll claim you need a bank processing fee. They'll keep doing this as long as you are gullible enough to keep sending them money.
Remember random strangers on the Internet can lie to you with impunity.
